# Object Required - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, object

Struggling with this error - I'm not too familiar with object oriented programming so I might just be messing up the syntax or something. I've simplified my code down to show only what seems to be causing the problem and the related variables:

```
Type layer
    Step As Variant
End Type

Sub PullData()
    j = 6

    Do While a <= j
        steps(1, a) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & a)
        a = a + 1
    Loop

    a = 1
    For a = 1 To j
        If steps(1, a) = 0
        layer.Step = steps(1, a)
        'From here there is a bunch of code where I use that value to copy a 
        'bunch of other values in the worksheet and paste into a different one, 
        'then move onto the next "item" in the array
    Next a
End Sub
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is take a range of data from a worksheet, convert that range into a one dimensional array, and then set `layer.Step` equal each of those values through each iteration. The error is happening at `layer.Step = steps(1, a)` in the second loop.

Comment: You haven't declared `layer` in your subroutine.  If you put `Dim layer as layer` at the beginning of the `PullData` subroutine, do you still get the error?  I'd recommend naming the variable something else, so you have `Dim myLayer as layer` and then `myLayer.Step = steps(1,a)` to help with the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple things that you're doing wrong here. I'm going to list them out:

- First of all, `steps` is a two dimensional array. To declare a one dimensional array, you don't need the `1` part, you simply declare it like this: `Dim steps(n) As variant`
- In your code, you started an `If` condition, but you didn't finish it (perhaps it's not the case in the original code).
- Now about your error: you declared a user-defined type (`layer`) but you never created a variable of it. You can't just use the type name. You can create a variable of type `layer` like this: `Dim myLayer as layer`, and then you need to replace `layer.step = '..` with `myLayer.step = '..`.

A working example that you can modify to suit your requirements:

```
Type Layer
    Step As Variant
End Type

Sub PullData()
    Dim steps(7) As Variant
    Dim j As Integer: j = 6
    Dim a As Integer: a = 1
    Do While a <= j ' it's better here to use `For` loop instead.
        steps(a) = Sheet1.Range("B" & a)
        a = a + 1
    Loop

    Dim myLayer As Layer
    For a = 1 To j
        myLayer.Step = steps(a)
        ' Rest of your code
    Next a
End Sub
```

Hope that helps :)